# how to check for the class fully?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am using androids fully Kiosk browser that uses the chrome Webview. But some methods or functions from javascript dont work correctly like the `window.print()`. But you can use instead `fully.print()` for the fully Kiosk App. But if I use the Website on a normal browser, the class 'fully' obviously doesnt exist.

How can I check for such a class (or object, (what if even is that called?))?

So what I basically want to do, is to use `window.print()` whenever its possible and `fully.print()` whenever that is possible, but `window.print()` not. Maybe something with try and catch?

Comment: `if(element.classList.contains('fully')){ /* element.className (class in HTML) contains fully */ } else { /* element.className (class in HTML) does not contain fully */ }`

Comment: I meant the js class fully, if that is even a class. not a DOM class.

Comment: `if(typeof fully === 'function')`

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Then you don't really have a class named `fully`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their "interesting" documentation, I found this that can be used to detect if it's fully browser:

```
<!-- Identify Fully Kiosk Browser -->
<script>
if (typeof FullyKiosk !== "undefined")
  document.writeln("<h1>Fully Kiosk working</h1>");
</script>
```

I found this in the Javascript section of their [configuration section](https://www.ozerov.de/fully-kiosk-browser/#configuration) on their page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think their page is too overloaded with information, that makes it difficult to filter the important information. But maybe I just didnt searched long enough.

Comment: It detects now correctly the kiosk Browser, but it doesnt print. I'll look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the **JavaScript API** in Fully Kiosk **Advanced Web Settings**. Then you can use this code:

```
<script>
if (typeof fully !== "undefined")
  fully.print();
else
  window.print();
</script>
```